# Why is same-origin-policy blocking this javascript call on a local domain?

Tags: javascript, same-origin-policy

I've got a local dev site running on http://mysite.local/
(it's a Django admin site with [Grappelli](https://grappelliproject.com/) installed, if that's any relevance).

The admin site opens a popup window for some operations (i.e. via `showRelatedObjectLookupPopup()`)

Due to previous similar issues with same-origin-policy (in production, the admin site loads some URLs from a CDN domain, which can trigger it) we have a "normaliser" JS function that explicitly sets:

```
document.domain = "mysite.local";
```

Both in the parent and in the popup, on page load.

The popup contains a link with an onclick handler that triggers a JS function in the parent:

```
onclick="opener.dismissRelatedLookupPopup(window, '422'); return false;"
```

Clicking this link in Chrome or FF results in a similar browser error:

> Permission denied to access property "dismissRelatedLookupPopup" on
>   cross-origin object

or

> Blocked a frame with origin "http://mysite.local" from accessing a
>   cross-origin frame.

Both the popup and the opener URLs share the same protocol, domain and port.

This is only an issue on the local domain. On dev/uat/production sites, (i.e. dev.mysite.com), all of which have their domain set to the superdomain "mysite.com" by the above "normaliser" function, the popup can successfully call the JS function in the parent.

What's stopping it on the local domain? What have I missed?

Comment: But... isn't `.local` considered a top-level domain in this case? A browser wouldn't consider `mysite.net` to be different in this regard from `mysite.com`: why would it consider `mysite.local` to be? Changing the domain that the site runs on locally isn't a trivial task, and before we do that I'd like to understand exactly what it is about our setup that's triggering SoP.

Comment: yes you are probably right and my first comment was before having enough morning coffee. Using `document.domain` can be tricky though. Have had lots of problems with it in the past inside frames

Comment: One thought....what is value of `document.domain` in parent page? Another thought is use a server side proxy to get the content for the iframe

Comment: `document.domain` is set to "mysite.local" in both the parent and the popup, on their respective onloads. And there isn't - AFAIK - any iframe involved. The popup is trying to call a JS function in the parent, and is being blocked as soon as it tries to access that JS function. I'm increasingly leaning towards your suggestion of running local as `local.mysite.com`, although I still can't see how it's materially different from a SoP perspective...

Comment: Ok I forgot was new window not frame. Shouldn't have to set `document.domain` in parent though only in new window. So I'm wondering what value of `document.domain` is inside parent

Comment: It's "mysite.local".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that switching the local domain, as per the original suggestion from @charlietfl, has indeed fixed the issue. It now runs locally as `local.mysite.com` instead of `mysite.local`, and the same-origin error has gone. I'm still unclear on what was triggering the error (was it because the the domain had only two parts as opposed to three? Was it something specific to domains ending in ".local"?) but in the unlikely event that anyone else trips up on this, that's what fixed it for me.